# Is there a way to crawl a S3 bucket with AWS Glue that requires Requester Pays?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I need to create a crawler on AWS Glue to catalogue some tables that I usually query on CLI by using
something like this:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://bucket/path/ --request-payer requester
```

but when creating a crawler I can't figure out where I need to configure the [requester pays](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ObjectsinRequesterPaysBuckets.html) option, so I'm getting this error log:

```
 ERROR : User does not have access to target
```

Any thoughts?

I'm using the AWS console for that.

Comment: [Access S3 Requester Pays Buckets in AWS Glue, Amazon EMR, or Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/requester-pays-buckets-glue-emr-athena/)

Comment: The documentation cited above refers to AWS Glue Job using Spark and not the Crawler in particular

Comment: This is currently not supported.